# Android Application is crashing when I used CSV file as database with a good number of entries

Tags: android, android-studio, csv, authentication

I am using Android Studio to create my project. In my project I have created a LoginActivity and I ma using the CSV file which I have included in my assets folder.
I have added say 500 Email Ids and password, the application is running fine. But if I add 1500 entries the application is crashing.
How can I deal with this type of problem?

Comment: How big would the csv grow? why not store your data in a database?

Comment: Is there any reason youre using a csv file to store your data? Wont that limit the email and password to a single device. Unless the csv file is shared amongst all the users which is a huge security concern.

Comment: `But if I add 1500 entries` When and where are you trying so? And who is trying? If your Android app tries to do so then show your code. And post the code where your app is crashing. And post the stack trace. And tell which exception lets your app crash. Further: nothing against a .csv file.